# Проблема с парсингом OLX

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой парсинга сайта OLX. Для получения номера нужно нажать на кнопку но при использовании request и  bs4 нажать никак(Нужны именно они а не selenium) Я подумал возможно проверить в запросах при нажатии на кнопку и да запросы идут.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот когда пытаюсь добыть номер с api  не выходит ничего.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можете кто то подсказать что не так делаю? Возможно там еще проверки есть но я не очень силен в програмировании. Апи добывал вот так.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.olx.ua/api/v1/offers/385076614/'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.content)
print(data)
```

Ссылка на обяву
https://www.olx.ua/d/obyavlenie/pamyatnaya-banknota-160-let-so-dnya-rozhdeniya-ivana-franko-IDq3K18.html?reason=ip%7Clister

Comment: @Александр это внутренний API. И никакой документации в публичном доступе быть не может.

Comment: Как тогда быть? Что нужно сделать для того что бы получить номер?

Comment: Александр. Вывод такой что есть еще какой то запрос который передает то самое значение что кнопка нажата. Верно?

Comment: @Александр и это не запрещает мне высказываться. Автору  - для получения номера там идет отдельный запрос на `https://www.olx.ua/api/v1/offers/784946042/limited-phones/` (смотрите свои скрины). На самой странице товара номера разумеется нет. И этому запросу нужны токены авторизации, отпечаток и т.д (смотрите хидеры запроса).. Это такая защита как раз от такого парсинга. ps: в объявлении из вашего вопроса телефон даже в браузере не получить - кнопка неактивна

Comment: -______________

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что с этим запросом идет Bearer токен. Он уникальный, в каждом запросе меняется. С ним номер можно получить. Это легко проверить, скопировав этот токен и добавив его в запросе в заголовки. Но если речь идет о парсинге большого к-ва объявлений, то нужно этот токен каким-то образом получать. Почитав инфу по их Апи, уяснил, что каждому зарегиному юзеру в их системе (тут: [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://developer.olx.ua/api/doc#section/Authentication/How-to-obtain-Access-Token)), выдается свой персональный токен, который обновляется раз в месяц. Руки не дошли до регистрации и попытке использовать его. Кто-то уже пробовал ? Или возможно нашли другой способ получения этого токена или некоего обхода этой защиты ?

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос. если вы заинтересованы в ответе на данный вопрос, то [зарабойтайте репутацию](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) и объявите [конкурс](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) на этот вопрос.